# Background of Windows 11 taskbar icons like in Windows 10

Tags: windows-11, taskbar

It's somewhat hard for me to discern Windows 11 opened vs. non-opened apps, because the taskbar icons background is not as salient as it was in Windows 10. Also, alerts are hard to see.

**Question**: Is it possible to change Windows 11 taskbar icons background color?

Here's a comparison:

**Windows 11:**

[image]

**Windows 10:**
[image]

Comment: I use a Blue TaskBar (Personalization) and the active Icons show up in Bright Blue. Works fine.

Comment: @John, the brightness is just not bright enough. I actually tried many colors, it all looks the same to me.

Comment: I am not sure why/  3 Windows 11 Pro machines here 2 Production 1 Insider and the active icons are very easy to see.  Standard daylight brightness.

Comment: If you would like to return to the Windows 10 taskbar and Start menu, you may use a third party product such as [Open-Shell-Menu](https://github.com/Open-Shell/Open-Shell-Menu).